# How to return images from an array and return nothing if array is an empty string ""

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am having issues rendering images from my json file. My data is structured like this and I want to map through and render the images but I am getting an error `item.image.map is not a function`.

```
"image": [
      "Apollo11PLSSSecondaryImage1.jpg", 
      "Apollo11PLSSSecondaryImage2.jpg"
    ],
"image": [
      ""
    ],
```

I've tried using `.filter` instead and also using an if else statement if the item.image is === "" return null.

```
<ArtifactImg>
      {
         item.image.map( item => {
             if(item === "") {
          return "N/A";
        } else {
         return <img src={require(`../../../shared/images/ArtifactImages/${item}`)}></img>
             }
          })
      }
</ArtifactImg>
```

Comment: Looks like your images array is an array of strings, not an array of objects that have a `image` property. You can try the following: `src={require(`../../../shared/images/ArtifactImages/${item}`

Comment: I changed return <img src={require(`../../../shared/images/ArtifactImages/${item.image}`)}></img> to return <img src={require(`../../../shared/images/ArtifactImages/${item}`)}></img> and now I am getting the error item.image.map is not a function

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Use [Edit] to add it to your question.

Comment: The change I suggested should not affect item.image.map, you must have changed something else too that broke that.

Comment: Could you provide valid input data structure? It isn't clear from your post. You can't have two "image" properties in one object.

Answer (score -2):

You're mapping image property, not items array. From what I saw, I guess, you have  to do something like this:

```html
<ArtifactImg>
      {
         items
           .filter((item) => !!item.image)
           .map((item) => {         
              return <img src={require(`../../../shared/images/ArtifactImages/${item.image}`)}></img>
           })
      }
</ArtifactImg>
```